# Toggling bootstrap5 dropdown from somehwere else in the document

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I have a dropdown toggle button in the navbar. But I want the actual menu to be shown in my body div.

Something like:

```
<div class="mainNav">
    <nav>
       [..content..]
       <a id="navbarSearch2" href="#myDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i data-feather="search"></i></a>
     </nav>
</div>
<div class="main">
     <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end py-0 me-sm-n15 me-lg-0 o-hidden animated--fade-in-up" aria-labelledby="navbarSearch2">
      [....]
     </div>
</div>
```

I can't get it to work, though. It only works when the toggler is directly before the dropdown. Otherwise, I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setAttribute')
    at Object.setDataAttribute (manipulator.js:34:13)
    at hi.show (dropdown.js:145:19)
    at hi.toggle (dropdown.js:124:49)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (dropdown.js:487:38)
    at HTMLDocument.n (event-handler.js:119:21)
``
```

Comment: Why do you have the href attribute set to `javascript:void(0);`, and not put the actual target reference in there, as https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/collapse/#example shows?

Comment: thanks. Tried that now (and updated the code above). Same error.

Comment: Not sure the dropdown component is actually able to handle this. Perhaps you could put the trigger element into the correct position, hide it - and then have your button trigger it via JavaScript, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/dropdowns/#methods

Comment: I think you're missing the `data-bs-target="#myDropdown"` on the `<a>` tag

Comment: @rhemmuuu: I had it, but a comment said that I should use "href" instead. So I switched to the code above. Have tried both.